# syntax error with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, lambda, actionlistener

This is part of the code of my small app, and i am having a syntax error for sure in the lines 50 and 85,can anyone help me with that and to check with you.this app is doing just one thing, on click on a button it takes you to choose txt file which app will read and change one word instead of the other and it is suppose to save  it with the same name :

```
 public void initListeners() {
    chooseFile.addActionListener(e)-> {
    JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser(new File("C:\\"));
        fs.setDialogTitle("Choose document to change");
        fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".txt", " New Text Document"));
        int result = fs.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            BufferedReader br;
            String fulltext = " ";
            try {
                File fi = fs.getSelectedFile();
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fi.getPath()));
                String line;
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    fulltext += line + "\r\n";
                }
                br.close();
                fulltext = fulltext.replace("tekst", "cs101");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

            }
            PrintWriter upis;
            try {
                upis = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Maksimovic\\Desktop\\tekstzaobradu.txt");
                upis.append(fulltext);
                upis.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Which are the syntax errors? Which are those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
.addActionListener(ActionEvent e)-> {
```

to

```
.addActionListener(e -> {
```

When using lambda short-cuts, you don't need or should have the type of the parameter present.  As for line 85 you will need to format your code better for us to understand it.

Edit, 85 needs a close-parenthesis to close out the `addActionListener` method call.

```
public void initListeners(){
    chooseFile.addActionListener(e -> {
        JFileChooser fs=new JFileChooser(new File("C:\\"));
        fs.setDialogTitle("Choose document to change");
        fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".txt"," New Text Document"));
        int result=fs.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            BufferedReader br;
            String fulltext=" ";
            try {
                File fi=fs.getSelectedFile();
                br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fi.getPath()));
                String line;

                int i=0;
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    fulltext+=line+"\r\n";
                }
                br.close();
                fulltext=fulltext.replace("text","cs101");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() );
            }catch(IOException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage() );
            }
            PrintWriter input;
            try {
                upis=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fi.getPath));
                upis.append(fulltext);
                upis.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Side note: if this were my project, I'd have most of that code in its own method to simplify and make easier debugging.

e.g.,

```
public void initListeners(){
    chooseFile.addActionListener(e -> chooseFileActionPerformed());    
}
```

Also look into using AbstractActions in place of ActionListeners. This can help in your separating your program logic from the view.

Side issue: Your file input and output code should be done off the Swing event thread and in its own background worker thread, such as provided by a SwingWorker. This should make your GUI more responsive.

Comment: Maybe this is easier for you to read? And about side note, you mean to make new method just for reading and writing file, and just to call him when i need it inside my ActionListener>

Comment: @Mapet: you're welcome. Also look into using AbstractActions in place of ActionListeners. This can help in your separating your program logic from the view.

Comment: @Mapet: Side issue: Your file input and output code should be done off the Swing event thread and in its own background worker thread, such as provided by a SwingWorker. This should make your GUI more responsive.

Comment: i have been reading about AbstractActions and i implemented it now, but could you help me with SwingWorker on mu example..

Comment: @Mapet: read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), and then try to implement it. If stuck, ask a new question about this, showing your compilable, runnable [mcve] code.